# curl to download file located at github

Tags: download, curl, github, file-download

I would like to donwload openjdk11 using cURL from github but the download stops just after few seconds, this is what I tried:

```
 curl -o openjdk11.tar.gz https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.1+13/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_openj9_jdk-11.0.1_13_openj9-0.11.0_11.0.1_13.tar.gz
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `-L` to follow redirects:

```
curl -L -o openjdk11.tar.gz https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.1+13/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_openj9_jdk-11.0.1_13_openj9-0.11.0_11.0.1_13.tar.gz
```